# Regex Query Mongodb $and operator result issue

Tags: java, regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB collection which contains 6 fields in single document, for example:

```
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("59d0f2382043f72a443e6ec0"),
     "TranDate" : "2017-07-25T18:01:12+08:00",
     "TranCode" : "ActFLA_A01_01_",
     "TranValue" : "812.34",
     "Seq" : "71",
     "Configuration" : "10"
},
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("59d0f2332043f72a443e1397"),
     "TranDate" : "2017-07-25T18:01:12+08:00",
     "TranCode" : "ActFLA_A01_01_",
     "TranValue" : "87.34",
     "Seq" : "71",
     "Configuration" : "10"
},
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("59d0f2332043f72a443e1397"),
     "TranDate" : "2017-07-25T18:01:12+08:00",
     "TranCode" : "ActFLA_A01_01_",
     "TranValue" : "828.34",
     "Seq" : "71",
     "Configuration" : "10"
},
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59d0f2342043f72a443e16be"),
        "TranDate" : "2017-07-25T00:45:02+08:00",
        "TranCode" : "ActFLA_A01_01_",
        "TranValue" : "0.00",
        "Seq" : "2",
        "Configuration" : "0"
}
```

Here is my code for query:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^2017-07-25"); 
Pattern regex2 = Pattern.compile("^ActFLA_A");
Pattern regex3 = Pattern.compile("^10");
DBObject clause1 = new BasicDBObject("TranDate", regex);  
DBObject clause2 = new BasicDBObject("TranCode", regex2);
DBObject clause3 = new BasicDBObject("Configuration", regex3);
BasicDBList and = new BasicDBList();
and.add(clause1);
and.add(clause2);
and.add(clause3);
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$and", and);
```

I am getting only one Document but I am expecting 3 Documents which contain (Fields) TranDate, TranCode, TranSeq and Configuration with same value except TranValue.

Comment: I would not save dates in string form. This makes database filtering for it harder than necessary. Anyway your code is defect as the clauses are never added to the `BasicDBList and`. And you should add the code you use for retrieving the matches. May be the problem is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question implies that you are interested in returning the (three) documents which meet all of the following conditions:

- `TranDate` starts with `2017-07-25`
- `TranCode` starts with `ActFLA_A`
- `Configuration` starts with `10`

The following code will meet that requirement:

```
@Test
public void aQuery() {
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClientFactory().create();

    MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoClient.getDatabase("stackoverflow").getCollection("ors");

    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^2017-07-25");
    Pattern regex2 = Pattern.compile("^ActFLA_A");
    Pattern regex3 = Pattern.compile("^10");

    Bson clause1 = Filters.regex("TranDate", regex);
    Bson clause2 = Filters.regex("TranCode", regex2);
    Bson clause3 = Filters.regex("Configuration", regex3);

    Bson query = Filters.and(clause1, clause2, clause3);

    Assert.assertEquals(3, collection.count(query));

    // let's have a look at the matched docs ...
    FindIterable<Document> documents = collection.find(query);
    for (Document document : documents) {
        logger.info(document.toJson());
    }
}
```

Given the sample documents included in the OP, the above test logs the following:

```
2017-10-01 17:31:59 [main] INFO  c.s.mongo.MongoClientTest - { "_id" : { "$oid" : "59d0f2382043f72a443e6ec0" }, "TranDate" : "2017-07-25T18:01:12+08:00", "TranCode" : "ActFLA_A01_01_", "TranValue" : "812.34", "Seq" : "71", "Configuration" : "10" }
2017-10-01 17:31:59 [main] INFO  c.s.mongo.MongoClientTest - { "_id" : { "$oid" : "59d0f2332043f72a443e1397" }, "TranDate" : "2017-07-25T18:01:12+08:00", "TranCode" : "ActFLA_A01_01_", "TranValue" : "87.34", "Seq" : "71", "Configuration" : "10" }
2017-10-01 17:31:59 [main] INFO  c.s.mongo.MongoClientTest - { "_id" : { "$oid" : "59d11663c26584cd8b7a0ee8" }, "TranDate" : "2017-07-25T18:01:12+08:00", "TranCode" : "ActFLA_A01_01_", "TranValue" : "828.34", "Seq" : "71", "Configuration" : "10" }
```